# "black box" preconditioner for shifted linear systems?

Tags: linear-solver, preconditioning

Does anyone know of any strategies for creating a preconditioner $P^{-1}_\sigma \approx (A+\sigma I)^{-1}$ given a preconditioner $P^{-1} \approx A^{-1}$, preferably such that the precomputation doesn't depend on the value of $\sigma$?